# Bash script that calls a program with some asterisks in arguments

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I’ve spent last hour or so trying to write a pretty simple bash script and I never felt so dumb.

So I have a list of strings (which are package selector specifications for a package manager, if that matters) which might contain asterisks. I need to build a command line preserving those asterisks and then call a program. Here is my naïve attempt:

```
xs="foo/bar */*"

xs_cmd=""
for x in $xs; do
  xs_cmd="$xs_cmd  -0 $x "
done

echo $xs_cmd
```

I need the `echo` call to be equivalent to

```
echo   -0 foo/bar    -0 '*/*'
```

which outputs `-0 foo/bar -0 */*`.

*P. S. In reality the first line is slightly more complex:* `xs="$some foo/bar */* $(get_others)"`*.*

---

If you run this script in a directory containing `a/b`, you’ll get `-0 foo/bar -0 a/b` instead.

When I change the last line to

```
echo "$xs_cmd"  # note the quotes
```

I get `-0 foo/bar   -0 a/b`
and, first of all that’s not what I want, since now I’m invoking `echo` with a *single* argument, and furthermore that tells me that the expansion is happening earlier, likely in the `for` loop.

But I can’t change the `for` line because

```
for x in "$xs"; do  # note the quotes
```

will just make the loop iterate only once: `-0 foo/bar */*` (there is a single `-0`)
so adding those quotes is not an option for sure.

Now if I revert back to the original script and replace the first line with

```
xs="foo/bar '*/*'"  # note additional single quotes
```

I get `-0 foo/bar -0 '*/*'` (single quotes should’t be there).

It seems that I tried every combination of quotes and backslash-escapes of asterisks and I have literally no idea what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I used your original script, but with single quotes on the first line (only) and it worked as I think you want it (`-0` before each file path):-

```
xs='foo/bar */*'

xs_cmd=""
for x in $xs; do
  xs_cmd="$xs_cmd  -0 $x "
done

echo $xs_cmd
```

You will probably find problems when you come to use it if there are embedded blanks in any of the file paths. If so change the command in the loop to:-

```
  xs_cmd="$xs_cmd  -0 \"$x\" "
```

Comment: Errr, no, this still performs expansion in the `for` loop and outputs `a/b` instead of `*/*`. Another problem is that the first line is somewhat more complex in reality; I’ll update the question in a minute.

Comment: I thought you wanted it expanded in the `for` loop. I tested it on Ubuntu 14.04 and got `-0 "foo/bar" -0 "dir/file" -0 "dir/file" ...`

Comment: You might want to read my question again, especially the part right before the horizontal ruler that gives the desired output: _no_ expansion should be performed; I need all the asterisks left in place.

Comment: OK. I have found something that works. Make your first line `xs="foo/bar @/@"`, then after your `for` loop add the line `xs_cmd=$(echo $xs_cmd|sed "s/@/\*/g")`. If you can't find a character such as `@` which is not in any of your file names, then use `xs="foo/bar ///"` and `xs_cmd=$(echo $xs_cmd|sed "s-///-\*/\*-g")`. I suggested using `@` first as it is easier to generalise for other strings with asterisks.

Comment: So, now I have `xs_cmd` which is a string with some asterisks. How do I pass it to the command (`echo` in my example)? `echo $xs_cmd` will perform expansion. `echo "$xs_cmd"` will invoke `echo` with a single argument.

Comment: I mean, shell programming is truly insane. I could have written this program in any other language in like two minutes and make it work in just one attempt. But now I really want to know how to write this in shell!

Comment: Since you are fighting against file name expansion, why not disable it in this context with `set -f` and restore it afterwards with `set +f`?

Comment: Ah, of course! Well, I’d classify this as a workaround, not a true solution (because I’m still interested how to do this directly), but that works. Thank you!

Comment: I have been thinking about your comment, and I don't conclude it is a work-round. Your script fails because asterisks are being expanded when you don't want them to be, so stopping their expansion at the wrong time constitutes a solution, because it's precisely what the other proposals are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, your either need to quote these `*/*`:

```
xs="foo/bar '*/*'" #!

xs_cmd=""
for x in $xs ; do
    xs_cmd="$xs_cmd  -0 $x "
done

echo $xs_cmd
eval echo $xs_cmd
eval "echo $xs_cmd"
```

or use arrays, or both:

```
xs=("foo/bar" "*/*") #!

xs_cmd=""
for x in "${xs[@]}"; do
    xs_cmd="$xs_cmd  -0 '$x' " #!
done

echo "$xs_cmd"
eval "echo $xs_cmd"
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, your first suggestion results in the following output: `-0 foo/bar -0 '*/*'`, which means the quotes are literally passed to the program. Your second suggestion results in `-0 'foo/bar' -0 'a/b'` which _both_ passes quotes to the program **and** performs expansion, while I need neither.